# Exceptions are not received in caller when using ASYNC

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, exception, async-await

I am using `DispatcherTimer` to process a method at a specified interval of time

```
dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer()
{
   Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 1, 0)
};
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
```

Here is the `dispatcherTimer_Tick` method

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        Task.Run(() => MethodWithParameter(message));
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {        
    }
}
```

Here I am calling `MQTTPublisher` which is a DLL reference.

```
private async static void MethodWithParameter(string message)
{
    try
    {
        await MQTTPublisher.RunAsync(message);    
    }
    catch (Exception Ex)    
    {       
    }            
}
```

I am not able to catch the exceptions which are thrown in that DLL. How can I get exception to caller?

**Definition of RunAsync** - This is in separate dll.

```
public static async Task RunAsync(string message)
{
    var mqttClient = factory.CreateMqttClient();
    //This creates MqttFactory and send message to all subscribers
    try
    {
        await mqttClient.ConnectAsync(options);        
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("### CONNECTING FAILED ###" + Environment.NewLine + exception);
        throw exception;
    }
}
```

And

```
Task<MqttClientConnectResult> ConnectAsync(IMqttClientOptions options)
```

Comment: For started don't use `async void`, if Microsoft could push a button to hurt the coder every time someone used `async void` they would. in fact i'm sure most of the SO users would too.

Comment: Also what is RunAsync()?

Comment: RunAsync is a method name . it can be any name. Any better solution?

Comment: Show us the definition for that method, and dont make it a comment :)

Comment: @TheGeneral the `async void` thing is just allowed on event methods. Otherwise yes, use the damn `async Task` !

Comment: updated question with definition @TheGeneral

Comment: How do you knwo an exception is happening?

Comment: I know im going down the rabbit-hole here, but what is the definition of ConnectAsync... or maybe i should ask, at any point to the DLL call are you using `async void`

Comment: when server is down, i got exception and cought in "catch (Exception exception){}".

Comment: Task<MqttClientConnectResult> ConnectAsync(IMqttClientOptions options); It's part of MQTTnet library, MQTTnet.Client , any best practice u suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the downside of using `async` void. Change your method to return `async Task` instead :

```
private async static Task MethodWithParameter(string message)
{
    try
    {
        await MQTTPublisher.RunAsync(message);

    }
    catch (Exception Ex)    
    {

    }            
}
```

Based on: [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

> Async void methods have different error-handling semantics. When an exception is thrown out of an async Task or async Task method, that exception is captured and placed on the Task object. With async void methods, there is no Task object, so any exceptions thrown out of an async void method will be raised directly on the SynchronizationContext that was active when the async void method started.

And:

> Figure 2 Exceptions from an Async Void Method Can’t Be Caught with Catch

```
private async void ThrowExceptionAsync()
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException();
}

public void AsyncVoidExceptions_CannotBeCaughtByCatch()
{
    try
    {
        ThrowExceptionAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        // The exception is never caught here!
        throw;
    }
}
```