# Async Task exception not being caught in Try-Catch

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am trying to cancel a `Socket.ReceiveAsync()` call by calling `Socket.Close()` and handling the inevitable `SocketException`.

My problem is that the exception never seems to make it to the `try/catch` in the calling function. Like this:

```
public async Task DoSomethingAsync()
{
    Try
    {
        while(true)
        {
            await DoSomethingMoreSpecificAsync();
            ....
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        do some logging... <-- exception never makes it here
    }
    finally
    {
        cleanup stuff();  <-- or here...
    }
}

public async Task DoSomethingMoreSpecificAsync()
{
    var read = await _sock.ReceiveAsync(...); <-- Exception is thrown here
}
```

So when the exception is thrown, the application never makes it to the `catch` or `finally` blocks. It just complains of an unhandled exception. AFAIK `async Task` methods should propagate their exceptions upwards like any other method. I know that this would be normal if I was using `async void`...

In the console, after the app has crashed, I see this:

> terminate called after throwing an instance of 'PAL_SEHException'

Here is the actual code:

```
private async Task DoReceiveAsync()
{
    var writer = _inputPipe.Writer;
    Exception ex = null;

    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var mem = writer.GetMemory(TLS_MAX_RECORD_SIZE);
            MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(mem, out ArraySegment<byte> buf);

            //Since OpenSSL will only gve us a complete record, we need a func that will piece one back together from the stream
            await ReadRecord(mem); 

            var res = _ssl.Read(buf.Array, TLS_MAX_RECORD_SIZE);

            writer.Advance(res);

            var flush = await writer.FlushAsync();

            if (flush.IsCanceled || flush.IsCompleted)
                break;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) { ex = e; }
    finally { writer.Complete(ex); }
}

private async Task ReadRecord(Memory<byte> mem)
{
    MemoryMarshal.TryGetArray(mem, out ArraySegment<byte> buf);

    SslError res;

    do
    {
        var sockRead = await _socket.ReceiveAsync(buf, SocketFlags.None);

        if (sockRead == 0) break;

        _ssl.ReadBio.Write(buf.Array, sockRead);
        var sslRead = _ssl.Peek(peekBuf, TLS_MAX_RECORD_SIZE);

        res = _ssl.GetError(sslRead);

    } while (res != SslError.SSL_ERROR_NONE);

    return;
}
```

Comment: Based on this try catch seems to have problem only with Task void methods, but you can still read the link mentioned in this answer, it might helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/50617278/2946329 I mean this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx

Comment: The exception raised in ReadRecord() is unhandled - it should be try-caught inside that method. When the GC notices the unhandled exception it bubbles up to the TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException handler. REF: [Async & exceptions in C#](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ptorr/2014/12/10/async-exceptions-in-c/)

Comment: The code you presented looks ok but problem is that we don't know the type of `_socket`. Presumably it's `Socket` which leads to the following considerations. The `Socket` type doesn't provide `ReceiveAsync` which would return `Task` out from the shelf so there should be some extension method and potentially a custom awaiter and both may have influence on the improper exception handling.

Comment: I suspect the "unhandled exception" message is just coming from Visual Studio, which is normal, and if you Continue, the program would behave as desired.

Comment: @StephenCleary Stepping through eventually leads to a warning about the process being terminated due to a "possible" stack overflow and `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'PAL_SEHException'` being written to the console...

Comment: `terminate` is a C++ method. I see you've got some OpenSSL calls in there, which is a library that requires incredibly advanced P/Invoke. Regardless, the first step in finding the problem is reducing the code to the absolute minimum that reproduces the issue.

Comment: Well, if the exception is not being caught (breakpoint on ex = e) then obviously it is not being thrown in the try block. So it is being thrown elsewhere.